# Syntax highlighting works for XAML but not for C# code

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

In the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020629/2383264, the syntax highlighting only works for the XAML code posted. I tried putting

```
<!-- language: lang-c# -->
```

before the first C# code block with no success. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your orignal markup was:

```
With the code behind as:
<!-- language: lang-c# -->
```

That's missing an empty line before the syntax hint comment thingy.

I added that empty line and changed to:

```
With the code behind as:

<!-- language-all: lang-c# -->
```

and it looks ok to me now.